# Releasing memory of a class which is calling a async method

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I have a code like this,

```
ClassA *reference = [[ClassA alloc] init];
reference.delegate = self;
[reference callAsynchMethod];
```

Here I am calling a asynchronous method. It takes around 4-5 seconds to execute. So how do I release the memory of ClassA? If I call release or autorelease this crashes.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make the object retain itself at the start of the `callAsynchMethod`, and then release itself after it calls (I presume) the delegate method that signals the end of the asynchronous work? Then, in the code above, you could release it immediately.

**Edit**

If you're talking about an `NSURLConnection`, then you should use an instance variable to reference the connection, and pass it a `release` in the `dealloc` implementation of your object.

Comment: I am trying to fetch a URL connection and parse the results. So that callAsynchMethod will trigger 2 callback methods either passed or failed. So after that method call I tried to release or auto release where it crashes. How am I suppose to retain it and release later?